# PHP + Shell Returning HTML

Tags: php, python, html, linux, shell

I am currently having an issue where I am trying to execute a shell script which interprets a file and echos back html, the shell script executes perfectly locally however when I try to execute through php it doesn't return anything, and seems are though php isn't executing it at all, I have a file which is created when the script is executed which doesn't show up with php execution. I have other scripts which are executed with php and work completely fine, and I have proper www-data permissions to execute this file. Please help me, here is the script I am trying to execute and the php file which is executing it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="font-size: 24px" scope="col"><p align="left" class="title_Font">Magnum Dongs <span style="font-size: 18px">&nbsp;|&nbsp; Mighty Meat Sticks 4 Kidz</span></p></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<ul align="center" width="1000" height="50">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Stories</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Memes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#email">Email</a></li>
</ul>
<table width="1000" height="386" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body_Main">
  <tbody>
    <?php 
    echo exec('./var/www/html/newdongs/fetch_html.sh');
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python3 /bin/dongs/db_Read.py >> lines
#1
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==11' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==41' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==31' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==21' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
#2
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==12' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==42' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==32' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==22' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
#3
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==13' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==43' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==33' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==23' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
#4
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==14' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==44' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==34' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==24' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
#5
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==15' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==45' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==35' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==25' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
#6
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==16' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==46' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==36' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==26' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
#7
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==17' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==47' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==37' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==27' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
#8
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==18' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==48' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==38' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==28' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
#9
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==19' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==49' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==39' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==29' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
#10
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col'>"
echo "table width='1000' border='0' class='post' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
echo "<tbody>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th scope='col' width='50'>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin:0px; ' align='center'> Posted By: "`awk 'NR==20' lines`"</p>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Total Score: "`awk 'NR==50' lines`"</p>"
echo "<img src='"`awk 'NR==40' lines`"'  width='150' height='150' alt=''/>"
echo "<p style='font-size: 0px; margin: 0px; ' align='center'> Upvote | Downvote</p>"
echo "</th>"
echo "<th scope='col' align='left' valign='top'>"
echo "<p class='post' style='font-size: 14px'>"`awk 'NR==30' lines`"</p>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</tbody>"
echo "</table></th>"
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: instead of exec() try with system()

Comment: I tried system() instead, still nothing. All the scripts have chmod 777, so they definitely have execution rights.

Comment: There could be so many things causing this.  Did you at least check the path to make sure the `python3` and `awk` are in it?  Do you look at the result of your calls to see if there's an error?

Comment: The code executes locally on my system without issue. I don't think its an issue with the shell script, I think its an issue with php not executing my script.

Comment: your python code looks like it's just generating an html why aren't you doing that with PHP?

Comment: I am no expert with PHP + MySQL databases, and I know that if done incorrectly PHP can be very dangerous in association with MySQL. Also, I am running a bunch of code to format the html properly and I am much better with python than I am with PHP.

Comment: Launching a subshell from PHP to generate HTML is making it unnecessarily difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with PHP looking for the script in the wrong location.

You can get the current working directory using `getcwd()`. Check if you are using the correct relative path to the script from your current working directory.

Else you could simply pass the absolute path to the script to the `exec()` command.

The next problem is your shell script prints quite a few lines and ends with the tags `</table></th>`. The `exec()` function returns only the last line of the shell script output. So the PHP output will show only the `</table></th>`. This cannot be rendered in HTML as they are only the closing tags. Hence you see no change in the browser but you can notice it if you inspect the HTML.

Instead you can use `shell_exec()` to return the entire output of the shell script.

Here is the corrected version:

```
<?php 
// 1.Remove the leading dot. The leading dot makes the path relative.
// 2.Use shell_exec instead to get all lines from your script output.
echo shell_exec('/var/www/html/newdongs/fetch_html.sh'); 
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by pass the aabsolute path to the script to exec()?

Comment: Absolute path is the path to the script from the root folder. Relative path is the path to script from the current working directory

Comment: Alright, thats what I thought you were saying. I am still not getting a return from php with your corrections.

Comment: I edited the post and added an example php file with the same execution which functions perfectly fine.

Comment: After I rebooted the server the php executed the script perfectly. So odd